# Angular universal page load twice in server side rendering ( ssr )

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I had added angular universal in the website due to this first page loads twice. Please someone Provide the exact answer to this question. After clicking view page source I want to see the whole code in. When I do like this

```
<section  style="background-color: rgb(202, 202, 202);" >
    <div class="container" style="background-color: #fff;">
        <router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
    </div>
</section>
```

I can inspect the code but the problem is page loads twice

but when I use this code in my code

```
  <section *ngIf="this.isBrowser" style="background-color: rgb(202, 202, 202);" >
        <div class="container" style="background-color: #fff;">
            <router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </section>
```

I can't inspect code but the loading time will reduce

What I will do to solve this problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey buddy, what's the implementation of onActivate(event: Event)?

Answer (score 2):

This is how angular universal works.

- your express server receives the request
- Angular app is bootstrapped server side and components are rendered server side (and so make API requests if needed).
- The page html is sent to the client browser
- Html is displayed
- Javascript is parsed
- angular app is bootstrapped client side, components are initialised and make the same API requests if needed